# IE11: different user agent strings for different requests, same web app

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, user-agent, internet-explorer-11

I have IE11 running in compatibility mode, to load a page it performs several requests (for css, js and so on). Sometimes it uses user agent

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

and sometimes

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

which makes my application think that someone tries to use hijacked session id and invalidate the session. I've tried several document modes (Edge, 10,9,8,7), behavior is the same.
If I turn off compatibility mode, everything works fine but It looks like a very strong restriction (IE on work machines is typically configured to work in compatibility mode at least for intranet sites, which my app is going to be).

So, the question is: **is there anything I can do from the web application side to deal with this issue, except for turning off session hijacking protection?**

**Update**

This thing doesnt always happen for the specific page, I can open it 4 times and nothing happens, but for the fifth time IE sends Mozilla/5.0 instead of Mozilla/4.0 and the app invalidates the session.

Comment: could you possibly be specifying a different compatibility mode X-UA-Compatible for different pages? Also have you accidentally flipped the browser into compatibility mode for the site?

Comment: I only have compatibility mode enabled for intranet sites, no specific settings besides that

Comment: microsoft is victim of their own paranoia. IE does hundreds of heuristics, including 2 different blacklists, one of them online, to trick webpages. They have tens of different UAs and want IE running websites whatever it takes. Unfortunately their methods only work for a "powerpoint presentation" in front of the typical Microsoft manager, but fail in the real world creating another bunch of more serious problems like the one you point. Chances are this will backfire again and encourage the developers to ban IE forever. As they say "IE is a great program to download an internet browser".